# Custom snippets trigger "&" not working in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to create a snippet with "&", but it doesn't show up. If I change the "&" to other words, it works. Why?

```
"&": {
      "prefix": [
         "&",
         "z&"
      ],
      "body": [
         "&__$1{",
         "   $2",
         "}"
      ],
      "description": ""
   },
```

Comment: I speculate [because `&` is the _menu-access-key_ symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/input/access-keys) in Microsoft software, and VSCode presumably will let you use `&` to denote an access-key for a Snippet menu item...?